# Why OWIN middleware is not implemented as some interface or abstraction class?

Tags: c#, owin

I cannot figure out why first parameter in method `IAppBuilder Use(object middleware, params object[] args);` of `IAppBuilder` interface does not require implementation of some interface, but simple object ?! 
I expected something like this

```
public interface IMiddleWare
{
    public void Invoke(IOwinContext context)
}
```

and

```
IAppBuilder Use(IMiddleware middleware, params object[] args);
```

Eventually this middleware has to be executed at some point, so what and how can be called if it is just object ??!! 
Also if middleware was some interface the following code would not be possible

```
public class SomeStupidMiddleWare
{
    public void SomeMethod1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("method1");
    }

    public void SomeMethod2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("method2");
    }
}

class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(new SomeStupidMiddleWare());
    }
}
```

But now this code is compiled successfully but generates runtime error `The type 'OwinEducation.SomeStupidMiddleWare' does not match any known middleware pattern`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems i have found an answer. As is pointed [here](http://mvenkatraman.co.uk/post/owin-katana-core-middleware-patterns) Katana supports 4 different convention based patterns for adding middlewares

1. Delegate Pattern
2. Instance Pattern
3. Generator/Nested Delegate Pattern
4. Constructor Type or Type Pattern

**Delegate Pattern**
Delegate pattern accepts the following delegate as a first parameter for the Use method of IAppBuilder and any number of additional parameter of any type

```
Func<AppFunc, AppFunc>
```

**Instance Pattern**
To use this pattern to add middlewares, we need newable types with the following two methods

```
public void Initialize(AppFunc next, params object[] args);
public Task Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> environment);
```

**Generator/Nested Delegate Pattern**
To use this pattern to create middlewares, we need a newable type with the following method

```
public AppFunc Invoke(AppFunc next, params object[] args);
```

**Constructor Type / Type Pattern**
A type with the following constructor and method can be added a middleware using this pattern

```
public Ctor(AppFunc next, params object[] args);
public Task Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> env);
```

So, IMHO, Considering that these cases has nothing in common that's why middleware is `object` in `Use` method and we cannot create some general interface for all of them

Answer (score 3):

The OwinMiddleware class is provided by Microsoft for easily implementing custom middleware with their implementation of an OWIN server (Katana) but OWIN is not a Microsoft only tech. By using middleware as an object, Katana can use non-Katana middleware that doesn't inherit from OwinMiddleware.

[This blog post](http://coding.abel.nu/2014/05/whats-this-owin-stuff-about/) talks about middleware signatures and implementation in more detail. The most important bit of information is that the only requirement is to have a signature matching

```
Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task
```

You can also check out the [OWIN site](http://owin.org/), and specifically the section on [Application Delegates](http://owin.org/spec/spec/owin-1.0.0.html#ApplicationDelegate)

Comment: `This blog post talks about middleware signatures` My concern is exactly about this. Everywhere is written that middleware have to have some specific signature, but `IAppBuilder.Use` for some reason accepts simple `object` ! As i understand somewhere inside `IAppBuilder` it is casted for needed type . But it's ridiculous

Comment: stackoverflow suggests me to avoid comments like "thanks" but i really thank you for attention for my question :) Especially that somebody found it as unclear

Comment: If you found the answer helpful you can accept it as the answer to the question.